# Complex Round Robin lead assignment rules

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, round-robin

I'm trying to create a complex system of lead assignment rules that will distribute leads automatically based on it's location and source. I've seen some videos on Youtube about how to make a basic lead assignment rule, but since this is a little bit more complex I would like to ask for your advice.

Rules:

- Split the leads evenly depending on their source (some sources are
  grouped as Inbounds and other ones as Outbounds) and location (leads 
  from a certain coutry should only be assigned to agents from that
  country);
- Outbound leads should only be assigned if there are no
  more    inbound leads left;
- Each agent can only have a maximum of 60
  leads    assigned;
- The number of agents may vary, so I should be
  able to    easily control the number of people that are receiving
  leads.

Can I receive some tips about the easiest way to do this?

Thanks in advance!